# How can i reduce video size in MB using ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a video of 120MB.I need to reduce its size to 20 MB without changing its quality.Is there any direct ffmpeg command which i can run?

I know the commands to reduce video size between specific time intervals and for resolution.Is there any way ffmpeg can reduce the size in MB?

Comment: `I need to reduce its size to 20 MB without changing its quality.` lol. When you find out how to do that, be sure to file a patent, you'll be a millionaire :)

Comment: This is awfully tagged, and not really on topic here. Please pay more attention to the tags in the future. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I need to reduce its size [..] without changing its quality.

That is generally not possible.

> I have a video of 120MB. I need to reduce its size to 20 MB

Welcome to video coding (and audio coding). Tell us something about the input file. Run:

```
ffprobe input
```

This will tell us how the file is currently coded. Then, let's work on re-encoding it. First, I'm assuming you don't want to change resolution/framerate, so we'll keep that the same. Second, let's select a video codec/encoder. Depending on the options built into your ffmpeg binary, the typical options are H.264 ([x264](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264)), VP9 ([libvpx](https://sites.google.com/a/webmproject.org/wiki/ffmpeg/vp9-encoding-guide)) or HEVC ([x265](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.265)).

There's various ways to encode videos (CRF 2-pass, VBR 2-pass), so which do you choose? Since you want a video of a particular size, you want VBR (CRF is if you want it to be of a particular quality and don't care about size). How do you calculate the bitrate? ffprobe tells you the duration of the video (in seconds), and target bitrate is calculated as:

```
target_rate_bits_per_second = target_size_bytes * 8 / duration_seconds
```

And then you use this bitrate as value for the `-b:v` option in each variable bitrate command I just linked to.

[edit] Assuming you have audio also, distribute the available bits between video and audio streams so that the total bitrate sum gives 20MB. Also assume a little bit of container overhead. [/edit]